# OpenCV проблема с вебкамерой

Tags: c++, opencv

При попытки считать изображение с вебки, выводит матовосерое изображение. Не подскажете в чем может быть проблема? OpenCV 2.2

Comment: не подскажете, почему OpenCV 2.2, если на дворе 3.2? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все, разобрался. Оказывается `openCV` поддерживает далеко не все камеры:(